# Need to use Quartz with Spring without configuration

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing java application that uses spring and hibernate and is deployed in AWS EBS environment.  I now have a need to support thousands of light weight but persistent jobs and am considering using quartz for managing those jobs.

First, does anybody who has done this before see any issues or has word of wisdom.  Second, I am looking for samples of managing a separate bean in this application that would start the scheduler so that it could run jobs, add more jobs or delete jobs that are not needed anymore.  All the samples that I have seen so far use xml configuration.  **My environment does not have any xml configuration**.  Are there any samples that I can use to accomplish this in a configuration-less spring environment.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Waqar

Comment: use quartz's native api, http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/quick-start.html you can register them with java it's a pretty neat and fairly concise API. with the latest quartz it was arguably the better option over springs APIs (That's what I decided we should do when I migrated spring quartz xml to javaconfig). Still using Springs Scheduler factory though.

Answer (score 0):

I think Camel can help you
http://camel.apache.org/quartz.html
http://camel.apache.org/cronscheduledroutepolicy.html

```
CronScheduledRoutePolicy startPolicy = new CronScheduledRoutePolicy();
startPolicy.setRouteStartTime("*/3 * * * * ?");

from("direct:start")
    .routeId("testRoute").routePolicy(startPolicy).noAutoStartup()
    .to("mock:success");
```

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution that would allow me to create a quartz scheduler bean using annotation.  I was thinking that once I have the quartz scheduler bean instantiated in the application, I can run the scheduler, create and delete jobs.